# SSH into computer which is connected to router via ethernet

Tags: ssh, openssh

I would like to SSH into my desktop which is connected via Ethernet to my router, from my laptop which is connected via WIFI.

I've done this before with two machines connected to the network wirelessly however the machine I wish to connect to is connected to the network with an ethernet cord.

Is there a way to do this?

OS: Arch Linux btw

Comment: Sure; Install OpenSSH Server on each machine

Answer (score 1):

In most SOHO WIFI deployments there is no difference in doing this on WIFI and Ethernet.  Typically WIFI takes Ethernet frames and adds / subtract "wifi stuff" to support the WIFI protocol, but otherwise are handled the same way by the OS/network stack. Because this is all happening below the IP level **you handle the setup identically to how you would do it ethernet to ethernet.**

It is possible, but not very common for WIFI to be on a seperate network.  In this case its a matter of ensuring the router handles the IP assignment, routing and firewalling correctly - and again, on the computer side, you treat WIFI and ethernet the same way. You would likely be on a corporate
network here, so speak to the IT department.

A few routers have "WIFI / LAN isolation" functionality enabled.  This would be a problem and should be disabled on the router if it exists.  There are other solutions, but they are complex and case dependent (eg setting up vpns through a commonly reachable endpoint.